# how to deploy full stack Laravel & Angular project

Tags: angular, laravel

I have E-commerce project, I am using Laravel as Backend APIs and Angular as the Frontend, now I bought hosting service and I wanna merge the two projects and upload it, can anyone help me what is how can I deploy and compress the project?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, stay on different servers.

But since you need it to be on the same server, you can upload the applications on different ports:

To deploy Angular:

```
ng build --aot
```

The build will be generated in the /dist directory
Complete documentation: https://angular.io/guide/deployment

An **alternative** is to use for example AWS S3 to place your front-end application and control the route using hash
e.g.  https://dev.to/svenfrese/how-to-deploy-your-angular-app-to-aws-s3-1341

Laravel deploy has several steps, certainly this tutorial is very complete:
https://medium.com/@decodeweb/11-easy-steps-and-deploy-your-laravel-project-from-git-to-shared-hosting-server-a90061201ac6

I hope I helped in some way.

Comment: and what can I do with laravel?